# Does Hawking radiation propagate inward into the centers of rotating black holes?

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation

Since most stars rotate and since the black holes so far observed appear to have resulted from the collapse of stars, I'm wondering whether the black hole radiation hypothesized by Hawking is expected to propagate into their otherwise empty centers, or only outward through their event horizons.

Comment: This article details the process: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation.   It points out that pair production occurs on the "safe" side of the event horizon, not inside it.

Comment: As I've accepted Anna's answer, I won't be posting a new one, but an answer more like the one I'd expected can be found in the next-to-last paragraph of the 2013 paper "Energy and momentum of the Universe", available free on Cornell U.'s Arxiv website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a heuristic](http://minerva.union.edu/diiorios/physics123/moreinfohawkingrad.html) image of the feynman diagrams , heuristic because it misses the gravitational vertex that will supply the energy for the reality of the escaping particle. :

[image: hawking radiation]

As depicted one particle of the pari can escape, and the other enters the event horizon and is eaten up by the black hole. They are generated close to the event horizon.

Comment: The separated particles remain entangled with each other.

Comment: @Edouard  until they interact  with another particle on their way,  yes

Comment: I've already accepted this good answer as to how HR might work, if it exists, but, rather than leave an impression that I'm convinced of its existence, I have to suggest that anyone curious about the possibility that it might should look at a 2019 alternative, shown at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.10819.pdf , which proposes that it might not exist, at least in the usual sense of radiation as propagating OUTWARD from an origin.

Comment: Sorry, but in the link you give Hawking radiation is not mentioned, must have  posted wrong link

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, Anna!  What I'm talking about is stated on the paper's p.2, in the 4th complete paragraph from its end, where Poplawski says, "The information goes from the parent universe to a baby universe formed on the other side of the black hole’s event horizon."  (I'd hesitate to call the "information" Hawking radiation, since I've never heard of any radiation that doesn't propagate outward, but it seems to serve the same function, in the bouncing cosmology he's describing, that HR serves in that more conventional version of inflation that's based on a scalar field.)

Comment: I'll be leaving shortly for a couple of days, so there's no rush on whatever reply anyone would like to make, but I'm hoping to post a question about Poplawski's paper, and I'll probably have to go thru Meta to try and get an "Einstein-Cartan Theory" tag added to the tags, as, although the paper on which I've commented is math-free, ECT definitely isn't, and his conclusions are based on it, not on GR.  (It's definitely mainstream physics, as Einstein seems never to have objected to its use of his name, which began decades before his demise.)

Comment: "Inward" & "outward" seem very confusing in black hole / white hole scenarios, but the info in question would seem, at a 1st guess, to resemble a "background" radiation (I'm picturing a smaller-scaled CMBR) in each "parented" local universe of that multiverse of temporal iterations which Poplawski has sketched.

Comment: Sorry, Anna; I'd forgotten to "ping" my last 3 comments to you, but I'm back in town now and should respond within a day or so, just in case you'd care to comment further.  (About radiation propagating backward, it's occurred to me that Feynman  was cited, by an author named Morris in a pop.-sci. book about "time's arrow", as having mentioned some sort of backward causation as a possibility, illustrated thru ripples on a pond:  It had some resemblance to black-hole-based cosmologies, with a causal boundary at the "pond's" edge.)

Comment: For some reason, the ping "@anna v" isn't taking on repeated attempts to edit my last comment, but, for other readers, I'd like to mention that ECT (AKA "ECSK") is based on conversations between Einstein & the mathematician Elie Cartan in 1927, and was elaborated decades later by Kibble & Sciama, all extremely well-reputed.

Comment: @Edouard I live in Greece and need my 8 hours . Also I am not into multiverses or tachyons, which do go backward

Comment: Anyway  my answer two years ago was not given in the context of multiverses, it is a simplified intuitive plot I found that helped me guess at the mathematics of hawking radiation.

Comment: --I understand. It just seems that, without an ECT or ECSK tag to distinguish it from GR (with which it is not identical, as pointed out by participants as well-reputed as Bob Bee), GR's singularity and QM's obsession with proving discrete space / time might continue to rule PSE into the far future.